# Horizontal UICollectionView's cell's content cut from top in iPhoneX

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have one screen which contains two `UICollectionView`, top most is for menu/options and bottom one for showing content for selected cell from top `UICollectionView`. I have designed entire screen in storyboard using auto-layout and constraints.

**Now my UI looks perfect in all devices except iPhoneX.**

In `iPhoneX` top most `UICollectionView` looks good. But the `UICollectionView` which is beneath top most `UICollectionView` is not showing content properly. `UICollectionView` is on right/proper position but its cell's (`UICollectionViewCell`) content cut from top.

For debug purpose I have coloured different views with different colours and attached below.

Here Yellow coloured view is background/container view of two `UICollectionView`, red coloured view is top most `UICollectionView` and purple coloured view is container view which contains all the controls of `UICollectionViewCell`.

[image: Here Yellow coloured view is background view, and purple coloured view is container view which contains all the controller of UICollectionViewCell]

Below is the debug hierarchy view of `UICollectioView` and `UICollectionViewCell`
[image: Debug hierarchy view of UICollectioView and UICollectionViewCell]

Below is the Debug hierarchy view of `UIView` which is cut from top inside `UICollectioViewCell` 
[image: Debug hierarchy view of UIView inside UICollectioViewCell]

Comment: Have you enabled safe area inside collection view cell?

Comment: can you enabled safe area, if enable then check your constraints :- give top constraints with safe area?

Comment: @Mansi are you talking about `Safe Area Relative Margins` checkbox available in `Size Inspector` in Storyboard? If so then yes it is already enabled.
And I have not enabled `Use Safe Area Layout Guides` options because it is only supported in iOS 9+ development targets.

Comment: Enable it, because iPhone X respects safe area layout guide and it has iOS 11

Comment: Then what about error which is rise due to enabling that option, because my app also give supports to iOS 8.

Comment: what error does it show

Comment: It shows `Safe Area Layout Guide before iOS 9.0` with error symbol in top right corner of storyboard where we can see all warnings and errors.

Comment: If possible you should try with minimum target 9, but if < 9 is important for you, then you need to either make conditional constraints for iPhone X by identifying the device (possible solution), or your design should be having larger top, left, right and bottom spacing (not recommended)

Comment: Yes conditional constraint is the solution, but I want to figure out why its cut from top, because For other UIKit controls also I have applied same type of constraint and all are looks perfect in iPhoneX without extra efforts. So may be there is something which I may be missed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170630/discussion-between-mansi-and-dhaval-d).

Answer (score 0):

It is better to give the full size of your collection view to your cell:

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
   
    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: collectionView.frame.height)
}
```

but if you need to give height for your specific cell you should specify y position for your frame of cell in the cell for item at indexPath:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    
    let cell: MyCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
    cell.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 0, width: collectionView.frame.width, height: myHeight)
    return cell
}
```